# Find a recurrence for the number of integer compositions of n which only have 1s and 2s as parts

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, integer-partitions

> Find a recurrence for $$i_n$$ the number of integer compositions of $n$ which only have $1$s and $2$s as parts.

How do you approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  what are the choices for the last part?  For each choice, how many compositions are there for what is left?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: if part is size 1, then if you remove it, there are (n-1) into parts of size 1 and 2. Then what if you remove the last part which is size 2?

Put it together and you got yourself the recurrence relation.